# Controlling read locks on table for multithreaded plsql execution

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have a driver table with a flag that determines whether that record has been processed or not.  I have a stored procedure that reads the table, picks a record up using a cursor, does some stuff (inserts into another table) and then updates the flag on the record to say it's been processed.  I'd like to be able to execute the SP multiple times to increase processing.

Obvious answer seemed to be to use 'for update skip locked' in the select for the cursor but it seems this means I cannot commit within the loop (to update the processed flag and commit my inserts) without getting the fetch out of sequence error.

Googling tells me Oracle's AQ is the answer but for the time being this option is not available to me.

Other suggestions?  This must be a pretty common request but I've been unable to find anything that useful.

TIA!
A

Comment: Don’t commit in loops? It’s generally frowned on. Why do you need to?

Comment: ...because I need to mark the row that's been picked up as having been processed surely?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I see. Not something I've tried I'm afraid. Perhaps you could do something with named locks using dbms_lock?